# Two NICs, Different Subnets

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have two NICs on a given machine (CentOS 7). One (say `enoX`) has an IP in the range `10.0.0.0/8` and the other one (say `enoY`) has an IP in the range `172.0.0.0/8`.

Now, I can access SSH and HTTP on `enoX` but not on `enoY`. I would like to be able to access on both, as I have these services listening on all interfaces.

Here is my routing table:

```
default via 10.39.30.254 dev enoX  proto static  metric 101 
default via 172.18.254.254 dev enoY  proto static  metric 100 
10.39.30.0/23 dev enoX  scope link 
172.18.0.0/16 dev enoY  scope link
```

What can I be doing wrong?

**Edit**

The output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The output on `netstat -lnp46`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      881/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2023/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      881/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2023/master         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7641            0.0.0.0:*                           18412/dhclient      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           18412/dhclient      
udp6       0      0 :::59186                :::*                                18412/dhclient      
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           622/NetworkManager
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -L` and `netstat -lnp46`?

Comment: Is the output of your machine, or the "given machine"?

Comment: "Given machine". The server.

Comment: And presumably, you have a machine which is on the same network as the `enoY` interface? If so, can you ping it? Also, it doesn't appear that you've got a running web server on the 'server' machine, so it's odd that you can connect at all with HTTP via `enoX`..

Comment: GregL I had made a quick test using `python3 -m http.server`. Yes, I have a machine on the same network. I think I figured what the problem was: I did `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2` and it started working :-)